# MySQL keyring issue

Tags: mysql, database, windows

I'm new with MySQL and i'm trying to install keyring on MySQL Community 8.0.11.

i'm using Windows and i edited my.ini file with

```
[mysqld]
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.dll
```

then i ran

```
mysql> install plugin keyring_file soname 'keyring_file.dll';
```

and i get a warning

```
       +---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------     --------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message |
    +---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 29 | File 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied) |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

i check if it was active and

```
mysql> SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS
-> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS
-> WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';
```

that plugin was active.

But when i try to modify my table with

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE example ENCRYPTION='Y';
ERROR 3185 (HY000): Can't find master key from keyring, please check keyring
plugin is loaded.
```

I don't get what i am missing.

plugin_dir is the correct one
(C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin)

and keyring_file_data is the same!

Comment: Have you read that warning all the way to the end where it says `Permission denied`?

Comment: yes, but i don't know why, i have admin permissions and privileges!

Comment: Make sure the (Windows) system user running mysql server can read the plugins directory.